# Juint Test suite fails to run from Pom file

Tags: java, maven, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a project in which I have used Juint5 for creating tests and test suites. I want to run the test suite via the pom file. Below is the pom file and test suit which I have created. when I run the `mvn clean`
it does not execute any tests but when I manually run the test suite `run as JUnit test` all the test cases are executed

can someone please help me here?

Suite file

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@SelectClasses( {TestA.class,TestB.class} )
@IncludeTags("unitTest")
public class Testsuite
{   
}
```

classes

```
public class TestA
{
@Test
    @Tag("unitTest")
  static void myMethod1() 
{
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }

  }


public class TestB
{
@Test
@Tag("unitTest")
  static void myMethod2()
{
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }

  }
```

pom file entry

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                <includes>
                <include>**/Testsuite*</include>
                </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

full pom file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <groupId>com.junit.karte.emo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cg-automation</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <!-- <packaging>jar</packaging> --> 
 
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <cucumber.reporting.version>5.3.1</cucumber.reporting.version>
        <karate.version>0.9.6</karate.version>
        <junit.runner.version>1.0.18</junit.runner.version>
        <commons.lang3.version>3.11</commons.lang3.version>
        <jsch.version>0.1.55</jsch.version>
        <junit.jupiter.engine.version>5.6.2</junit.jupiter.engine.version>
        <junit-jupiter-api.version>5.8.0-M1</junit-jupiter-api.version>
        <junit.platform.runner>1.6.2</junit.platform.runner>
        <cg_password>n</cg_password>
        <host_ip>10.204.100.136</host_ip>
        <host_usrname>root</host_usrname> 
        <host_password>n</host_password> 
        <build_name>change_guardian-6.2</build_name>
        <custom_path>/usr</custom_path>
        <cg_version>8.5.0.0.13</cg_version>
        <web_port>8443</web_port>
        <win_host>vlab007206</win_host>
        <win_ip>10.204.108.65</win_ip>
        <win_user>administrator@cgdom100.lab</win_user>
        <win_password>Control4321</win_password>
        <asset_type>win</asset_type>
        <unix_host>vlab007201</unix_host>
        <unix_ip>10.204.100.136</unix_ip>
        <unix_user>root</unix_user>
        <unix_password>n</unix_password>
        <base_build>change_guardian-6.1</base_build>
        <basecg_version>8.3</basecg_version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
        <maven.surefire.version>2.22.2</maven.surefire.version>
        <maven.site.version>3.7.1</maven.site.version>  
        <maven.surefire.report.version>3.0.0.M5</maven.surefire.report.version>
        <maven.project.info.reports.version>3.0.0</maven.project.info.reports.version>      
        <runSuite>StanderdPathInstall.java</runSuite>
        <groups>StanderdPathInstall</groups>
    </properties>    
    <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>sm.releases</id>
          <name>NetIQ Security Management site - RELEASES</name>
          <url>https://btpartifactory.swinfra.net:443/artifactory/security-sentinel-mvn-releases/</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>${repository-updatePolicy}</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>${repository-updatePolicy}</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>sm.snapshots</id>
          <name>NetIQ Security Management site - SNAPSHOTS</name>
          <url>https://btpartifactory.swinfra.net:443/artifactory/security-sentinel-mvn-snapshots/</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>${repository-updatePolicy}</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>apache.central</id>
            <name>Apache Maven Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>maven2-maven-org</id>
          <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>  
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.8.0-M1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
                    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>
            <version>${karate.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>            
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>${karate.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pantsbuild</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-runner</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.runner.version}</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>${jsch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.engine.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter-api.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.platform.runner}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Werror</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
               <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>StanderdPathInstall.java</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
            </plugin> 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.site.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>    
        <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>    
    </build>       
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.report.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.project.info.reports.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: You should try to use `<include>Testsuite.java</include>` instead? (details: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html)  assuming your are using the most recent version of surefire plugin?

Comment: Yes I am using the latest version, but adding like this also does not works

Comment: Not adding replace it with that what I have given..furthermore please show your full pom file...

Comment: "when I run the mvn clean it does not execute" - do you really mean that? You probably mean  `clean install` or `clean verify`?

Comment: ```mvn clean test ```

Comment: added full pom file in the details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is

1. Add @Tag annotation before each test which I want to run
2. Add tag  under the maven-surefire-plugin, e.g integration

```html
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>                    
                        <groups>integration</groups>
                    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

3. Run maven command: `mvn test -Dgroups="integration"`